# ForAll and filter with Iterator in OCL

Tags: uml, ocl

I need to do 2 functions in OCL that work on collection: forAll and filter. The trick is I can only use **iterator**.

This is what I come with:

```
context Collection(T)::forAll(expr) : Boolean
    body : self -> iterate(t: T, acc: Boolean = true | expr(t) and acc)

context Collection(T)::filter(expr) : Collection(T)
    body : self -> iterate(t: T, acc: Collection(T) = {} | if expr(t) then acc->include(t) else acc endif
```

Please tell me if it's right or wrong.

Comment: Hehe. That struck me the first sight. You should add OCL in the question :-)

Comment: I'm no OCL expert but it looks okay to me. Can I ask in which context you need that?

Comment: I'm preparing for OCL test and it was one of the example questions.

Comment: It's 100% academic code :).

Comment: I thought so. And in that case your teacher will eventually correct you ;-) But as said: it looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of `forAll` is fine, indeed it is the same as given in section 11.9 (Mapping Rules for Predefined Iterator Expressions) of [OCL Version 2.4](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.4/).

The `filter` operation is equivalent to the `select` operation that is defined by OCL in almost the same terms as you did, with the following differences:

- It should be `acc->including(t)` instead of `acc->include(t)`.
- `Collection` is an abstract type, then I suppose you cannot write `acc:Collection(T) = {}` because the actual type of `acc` would be undefined. Instead of that you could use `Bag(T) = Bag{}` (but in this case `Set(T)::filter(expr)` would return a `Bag` instead of a `Set`).

The OCL specification solves this issue by defining `select` separately for each collection type (then we have `Set(T)::select(body):Set(T)`, `Sequence(T)::select(body):Sequence(T)`, etc.) with a different accumulator type in each case.